# Spring Roo shell deletes my Roo_Controller.aj file after push in

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-roo

After pushing in a couple of methods, the roo shell will delete my aj file.

Just copying any of these methods to the main the Controller java file would cause this:

```
Deleted backoffice|SRC_MAIN_JAVA/xxx/actions/TicketController_Roo_Controller.aj - empty
```

I'm using a multimodule project is that makes a difference. My controllers are in a module, my entities in another module.  If the roo shell if not running, my pushed in method works correctly.

What could be causing this?

**Update**

Pushing methods in works in some of my other controllers that are backed by other entities.  I'm trying to track down the problem, it might have something to do with the Ticket entity, which has some extra finders and extra functionality.

Comment: Are you pushing all the methods from the .aj file back into your controller, or just some?

Comment: @CodeChimp I'm pushing a few methods, not all at once.

Comment: Can you post the code of the controller?  Also, I'm guessing you're using STS to do the pushing in...

Comment: I was able to boil down the issue to importing the entity directly vs importing it with a wildcard.  I posted a bug: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-3456

Answer (score 0):

Check the imports and see if wildcard imports are present .

Please remove wildcard imports and check again .

That resolved my issue.